# module.exports and local variables

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a small web app and I have a question about module.exports

supppose I have a file `counter.js`

```
var counter = 0;

module.exports = {
    add: function() {
        counter++;
    }, 
    get: function() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

and I try to reference this file in several files suppose `app.js` and `count.js` all located in the same directory

```
// from app.js

var a = require('./counter.js');

a.add(); 
console.log(a.get()); // the value is 1


// from count.js

var b = require('./counter.js');

b.add(); 
console.log(b.get()); // the value is 2?
```

will the value be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that (for example) `app.js` will include `count.js` via `require()` or that both `app.js` and `count.js` will be included by a third file via `require()`, then they all share an instance and the answer is `2`.

If you mean what happens if you run `node app.js` and then run `node count.js`, then in that case, every file gets its own instance of the required module, so it will be `1`.

Comment: is there any way to make the variable counter be shared by both files?

Comment: I mean that `app.js` and `count.js` are two seperate files including `counter.js` via `require()`

Answer (score 1):

The result will be 2

> From **nodejs.org** doc

Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) **that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned**, if it would resolve to the same file.

Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.